# How to query the dependencies of a flatpak app?

Tags: flatpak

On my machine I have four flatpak apps installed

```
$ flatpak list --app
Name                                    Application ID                Version          Branch         Installation
Obsidian                                md.obsidian.Obsidian          1.5.3            stable         system
GNU Image Manipulation Program          org.gimp.GIMP                 2.10.36          stable         system
Inkscape                                org.inkscape.Inkscape         1.3.2            stable         system
Shotcut                                 org.shotcut.Shotcut           23.12.15         stable         system
```

However, if I now query everyting flatpak has installed I see there are NVIDIA drivers

```
$ flatpak list
Name                                               Application ID                                                   Version              Branch                  Installation
Obsidian                                           md.obsidian.Obsidian                                             1.5.3                stable                  system
SWH                                                org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.swh                           0.4.17               22.08                   system
Freedesktop Platform                               org.freedesktop.Platform                                         23.08.10             23.08                   system
Mesa                                               org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                              23.3.0               22.08                   system
Mesa (Extra)                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                              23.3.0               22.08-extra             system
Mesa                                               org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                              23.3.2               23.08                   system
Mesa (Extra)                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                              23.3.2               23.08-extra             system
nvidia-535-146-02                                  org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-535-146-02                                         1.4                     system
Intel                                              org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                                                  22.08                   system
Intel                                              org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                                                  23.08                   system
openh264                                           org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264                                2.1.0                2.2.0                   system
GNU Image Manipulation Program                     org.gimp.GIMP                                                    2.10.36              stable                  system
GNOME Application Platform version 44              org.gnome.Platform                                                                    44                      system
GNOME Application Platform version 45              org.gnome.Platform                                                                    45                      system
Yaru-dark Gtk Theme                                org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark                                                           3.22                    system
Inkscape                                           org.inkscape.Inkscape                                            1.3.2                stable                  system
KDE Application Platform                           org.kde.Platform                                                                      6.5                     system
QGnomePlatform                                     org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform                                                  6.5                     system
QAdwaitaDecorations                                org.kde.WaylandDecoration.QAdwaitaDecorations                                         6.5                     system
QGnomePlatform-decoration                          org.kde.WaylandDecoration.QGnomePlatform-decoration                                   6.5                     system
Shotcut                                            org.shotcut.Shotcut                                              23.12.15             stable                  system
```

I want to be able to see which of the four applications that I installed pulled in `org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-535-146-02` as a dependency, but I don't know how to query for this information at the command line as `flatpak info` doesn't give the dependencies.

How can I determine what dependencies belong to what app?

Comment: From `flatpak history` it looks like it was Obsidian that installed the nvidia drivers, but I want to know how to query this information.